# AWS DMS Redshift as target

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am planning to do continuous migration of RDS to Redshift using DMS. As per the docs, it states if the target is redshift , DMS uses a S3 bucket to temporarily store the data before copying to redshift. I could not find any document confirming if this S3 bucket is temporary (used only for initial copying) and is deleted once the copying is done. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html)

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've figured out the answer already. If not, yes it does create a bucket and the contents are deleted but the bucket itself is not deleted. Generally the name of the bucket starts with dms-.
Also there is an option to provide a custom bucket.